# How can I create an executable research compendium (erc)?

Tags: reproducible-research

I have a manuscript for a scientific publication, the data, and the scripts used to generate the result figures and tables. How can I wrap these three in an executable research compendium, so that others can easily reproduce the computational steps my study?

Answer (score 4):

The best way is to use our online ERC user interface at 
**https://o2r.uni-muenster.de/**. There you can upload a zip file of your workspace, which must include an [R Markdown](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/) file that executes your workflow. You may choose to start you analysis from raw data or, if that takes very long, based on some pre-processed data.

The UI has a self-explanatory creation wizard guiding you through the process. Note that all your files will be publicly available on our demo server after your creation, and that you will need an [ORCID](https://o2r.uni-muenster.de/#/) account to log-in. New registrations are manually checked before you are allowed to upload any files, so please let us know if you're in a hurry.

---

You can also "manually" create an ERC as described in [this guide](https://o2r.info/erc-spec/user-guide/creation/) that is part of the ERC technical specification.